# How to insert values in MySql Using Java Servlet

Tags: servlets

I add full code Here. Check the following code which I am using to insert values in MySql. While executing the program, Values are not inserting.

Database  datab.java

```
Statement st=null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee","root", "1234");
     st=con.createStatement();
```

Servlet Code

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String s = "http://localhost:" + request.getServerPort() + ""
            + request.getContextPath()+"/Emp";

String a,b,c,d,e;

    try {
         a=request.getParameter("t1");
        b=request.getParameter("t2");
         c=request.getParameter("t3");
          d=request.getParameter("t4");
          e=request.getParameter("t5");
         System.out.println(a);
        datab dt = new datab();

     dt.st.execute("insert into employee(eid,emp_name,emp_age,emp_desig,emp_salary) values(a,b,c,d,e)");

     response.sendRedirect(s);
     } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();
        out.close();
    }          
}
```

Comment: Replace `ex.printStackTrace()` by `throw new RuntimeException(ex)`, and read the error message and stack trace you get. Your SQL query is obviously syntaxically incorrect (what are a, b, c, d and e for the database?). Then read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. In fact, read the whole JDBC tutorial, because your way of opening but never closing statements and connections is really bad.

Comment: @JB Nizet... The error is.....    java.lang.RuntimeException:         com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'
 AddEmp.processRequest(AddEmp.java:57)
 AddEmp.doPost(AddEmp.java:87)

Comment: What did I tell you...? Now read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a,b,c,d,e all are string 
Replace

```
insert into employee(eid,emp_name,emp_age,emp_desig,emp_salary) values(a,b,c,d,e)
```

with

```
insert into employee(eid,emp_name,emp_age,emp_desig,emp_salary) 
values('"+a+"','"+b+"','"+c+"','"+d+"','"+e+"')
```

Instead of something like this

```
dt.st.execute
```

You dont you make the `datab` class to return `connectionObject` and using that object create the `Statement` Object and execute the statements.

Please stop using Statement and take advantage of PreparedStatement something like this

```
String query = "insert into employee(eid,emp_name,emp_age,emp_desig,emp_salary) 
    values(?,?,?,?,?)"
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setString(1, a);
statement.setString(2, b);
statement.setString(3, c);
statement.setString(4, d);
statement.setString(5, e);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: u r correct....   dt.st.execute("insert into employee(eid,emp_name,emp_age,emp_desig,emp_salary) values('"+a+"','"+b+"','"+c+"','"+d+"','"+e+"')"); ...  This is working...

Comment: Dont read only the first part please read the whole answer and follow that instead of the first part

Comment: @SparkOn next time, don't even advise the first way. Newbies inevitably choose to do it that way because it's simpler to understand than the second. They don't realize it's also completely wrong. My 2 cents.